# json response iteration android studio/retrofit

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

This might be super simple but I am a newbie and doing this in android studio. This JSON parsing trips me up. Basically I just need the value for userName in this array. I was able to get the response to where I need to loop through each "owner" and get a userName and put it into a list. I can't figure out how to get the userName field. user name could contain @ or it could not. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your provided JSON hierarchy photo the name of the root element doesn't appear, so I assumed it as "root_element" in below script

- Here the entire JSON response can be read as a `JSONObject`.
- And as this `JSONObject` has multiple elements in it (in picture
  named as 0, 1, 2..); then you can get a `JSONArray` using
  `getJSONArray()` method.
- Then you can loop through this `JSONArray` to get a paricular element from the (0, 1, 2...)
- After that you can another `JSONObject` from this particular element which is `owner` in your JSON structure photo.
- And finally you can read Strings of this owner using `getString()`

```
String jsonResponse = ""; // Put the entire JSON response as a String 
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonResponse); // jsonResponse is the entire JSON string
JSONArray rootArray = root.getJSONArray("root_element"); // your root element is not show in your provided photo

for (int i = 0; i < rootArray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject element = rootArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject owner = element.getJSONObject("owner");
    String email = owner.getString("email");
    String givenName = owner.getString("givenName");
    String id = owner.getString("id");
    String lastName = owner.getString("lastName");
    String realm = owner.getString("realm");
    String userName = owner.getString("userName");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON library to convert **userListAccounts** into a ArrayList from which you can simply get the username for each element.

#### Add GSON Dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>gson</artifactId>
<version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Create your Model class for userListAccounts (for Kotlin)

```
data class UserAccount(
val creationTime: Int,
val deletionTime: Int,
val owner: Owner,
val status: String, // I assume the Datatype is string
)

data class Owner(
val email: String,
val givenName: String,
val id: String,
val lastName: String,
val realm: String, // I assume the Datatype is string
val userName: String
)
```

#### Create your Model class for userListAccounts (for Java)

```
class UserAccount {
Integer creationTime;
Integer deletionTime;
Owner owner;
String status;

public UserAccount(
    Integer creationTime,
    Integer deletionTime,
    Owner owner,
    String status
) {
    this.creationTime = creationTime;
    this.deletionTime = deletionTime;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.status = status;
}
}

class Owner {
    String email;
    String givenName;
    String id;
    String lastName;
    String realm;
    String userName;

    public Owner(
        String email,
        String givenName,
        String id,
        String lastName,
        String realm,
        String userName
    ) {
        this.email = email;
        this.givenName = givenName;
        this.id = id;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.realm = realm;
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

#### Convert JSON to Object using GSON Library

```
val gson = Gson();
val userAccounts: ArrayList<UserAccount> = gson.fromJson(userListAccounts, UserAccount::class.java);
```

#### Use this Object to access username field

```
val usernameList = ArrayList<String>()

for (account in userAccounts)
  usernameList.add(account.owner.username)
```

The usernameList will contain all the usernames present in your JSON response.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think that is Kotlin? I am using java in android studio not sure what the equivalent is.
I have made it further but now not sure how to "use" this...
                    `for (Account userListAccount : userList.getAccounts())
                        Log.i("Access", "UserNames from json;" +userListAccount.getOwner().getUserName());`
and its logging the usernames...but Not sure how to actually use this in like a dialogbox or list in toast for example.
`2020-04-22 19:28:52.638 18757-18757/com.test.myandroid I/Access: UserNames from json;tester@bla.com`

Comment: Edited the answer to include model class in java. I hope you can do the rest in java.